# AOSP 14 linux kernel: ERROR: modpost: "relay_*" [../mod_using_relay_*.ko] undefined

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, android-source, kernel-module

In common-android14-6.1-lts, I'm trying to export `relay_*` symbols by enabling CONFIG_RELAY, the output build kernel config is applied:

```bash
$ cat <path-to-kernel-out>/.config | grep RELAY
CONFIG_RELAY=y
```

Unfortunately the responding symbols are not exported (empty in Module.symvers):

```bash
$ cat <path-to-kernel-out>/Module.symvers | grep relay_
# <empty>
```

My expected result (Something like it which is present in common-android13-5.15-lts):

```bash
$ cat <path-to-kernel-out>/Module.symvers | grep relay_
0x5027d999      relay_switch_subbuf     vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0xf4a83683      relay_file_operations   vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x6de40b20      relay_open      vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x9f6fac6d      relay_close     vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0xe266f439      relay_flush     vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x64e293a9      relay_subbufs_consumed  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0xa2c6d402      relay_reset     vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
```

To fix kernel module compile time which depends on `CONFIG_RELAY`

```bash
ERROR: modpost: "relay_file_operations" [../<mod_using_relay_file_operations>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_open" [../<mod_using_relay_open>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_close" [../<mod_using_relay_close>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_flush" [../<mod_using_relay_flush>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_reset" [../<mod_using_relay_reset>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_subbufs_consumed" [../<mod_using_relay_subbufs_consumed>.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "relay_switch_subbuf" [../<mod_using_relay_switch_subbuf>.ko] undefined!
```